# "Have you got" with abstract things?

Tags: verb-usage

Can I say:

> "Have you got something that you always forget to do?"

Or should I use "have got" only with tangible objects that I can possess?

Answer (score 1):

That sentence isn't quite right, but that's because of its formulation rather than about possession and abstract objects. After all, the use of *something* in the sentence could refer to anything.

The problem with the sentence is that the verb in the first part should normally agree with the verb in the second part.

For example, both of these sentences would be fine:

> "Have you **got** something that you always forget to **get**?"
>   "Have you **done** something that you always forget to **do**?"

As would others of the same construction:

> "Have you **made** something that you always forget to **make**?"
>   "Have you **touched** something that you always forget to **touch**?"

And so on.

---

Note that one exception to this is the following:

> "**Is** there something that you always forget to ***[verb]***?"

Because of its nature, *is* can be used in this way with any other verb.

There is also a sense where **got** could be used in the same sort of way.

Consider this:

> "Think of a number from one to ten. Have you **got** it?"

In this informal use of the word, **got** is used to mean **thought of**. So, the sentence in question could be taken as an elliptical way of saying:

> "Have you **got** something *in mind* that you always forget to **do**?"
>   "Have you **got** something [] that you always forget to **do**?"

However, I suspect that this might come down to dialect and regionalism. For me, this kind of expression seems so awkward and unnatural as to be a mistake. While I would use *Have you got it?* on its own, as part of a broader context, if I used the longer sentence, it would always be the version that included *in mind*. But even then, it still sounds a little strange to me.

---

As for *have got* and tangible objects, it depends on what you mean by *tangible object*. (The fact that you need to possess something is accurate, however.)

You could ask all of these things:

> Have you got a sense of humour?
>   Have you got an understanding of advanced calculus?
>   Have you got an illness?

Those are all things that you would be considered to *possess*, however none of them can necessarily be pointed to as physical objects. Although things like *symptoms* of a cold can be seen and heard, the idea of being ill is somewhat abstract and non-quantifiable—especially if you're talking about mental illness rather than physical illness. Certainly having knowledge or understanding is abstract.

For most abstract things, it *would* be odd to say *something that you always forget to get*. But it might work in some contexts—such as getting a feeling of confidence or relaxation, which can be *got* (or obtained) through self-discipline and certain mental exercises.

---

Note that while there is nothing wrong with *have you got*, the more common phrasing is *do you have*.

Comment: "Have you got something that you always forget to do" is completely normal speech to me. "Have you done something you always forget to do" would just seem weird.

Comment: @SamBC I have updated my answer with the one possibility I can think of why *Have you got something that you always forget to do?* might sound normal to you. (It definitely does not sound *at all* normal to me.)

Comment: Maybe a dialect thing or something. Definitely something I would not think twice about on hearing, and quite possibly something I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Really basic thing to get out of the way... you can use *get*, and indeed *have*, about abstract or immaterial things. That's fine.

As to the question itself... yes, I consider that natural. Informal, but normal and natural and unexceptionable. However, that is probably a dialect thing, given Jason Bassford's answer.

I would explain it like this:

> "Have you got something?"

***Get*** is an amazing verb. If people are asked what it means, I suspect they would usually say something amounting to *obtain*, at least as their first response. But it means so much more. It can mean to cause something, to become something or change state, to understand (which is really by extension of the *obtain* meaning, I suspect), and various auxiliary uses. It has a particular usage in the perfect, as seen here, where it essentially means the same as "have". It could be written "Do you have something". So, with just the first half of your sentence it's just asking if the person has something. It might be asked while searching a room. One person makes an excited exclamation, and the other asks "have you got something?". Or if some people are all sitting around trying to solve a complex mathematical problem, one makes an excited exclamation, and the other asks "have you got something?". In that case, they would be seeing if the excited exclamation was because the person had made a breakthrough, found something that helps them move forward with the problem.

Completely natural.

Then your sentence continues,

> "...that you always forget to do?"

So we have a main verb for this phrase, *forget*. Then we have the adverb *always* and the verb complement *to do*. We have the subject *you*. We need an object as well; a standalone sentence of this would be "You always forget to do X", where X might be "your taxes". Either that, or another verb would take the place of *to do*, like *to bathe*. With *to do* as the complement, though, we don't have complete meaning, because *to do* is not complete on its own. However, this whole phrase is attached to *something*. It's "Have you got [something that you always forget to do]?" By the same pattern as the rephrasing above, we can read this as

> "Do you have [something that you always forget to do]?"

You could actually replace *something* with *anything* with largely the same meaning. Essentially, the question could even be rephrased

> "Is there anything that you always forget to do?"

And that's how I would probably phrase it formally. However, the "have you got" or "do you have" phrasing is a little more intimate, more about the person.

For example, someone might answer:

> "Yes, I always forget to lock the door."

Or keeping some details implicit from the question:

> "Yes, to put the cat out."

Of course, the *always* in question might be hyperbole, rather than literal.

---

Abstract things that you might say "have you got...?" about that are less prone to grammatical puzzlement...

> "Have you got an ambition?"
>
> "Have you got a favourite number?"
>
> "Have you got a degree?"

The question you ask, about *to get* with abstract things, is simple to answer. Your example complicates things a little, but whatever people might say about the grammar of that sentence otherwise, the object of *to get* being abstract is absolutely, unquestionably fine.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you interpret *Do you have something that you always forget to do?* Whether using *got* or *have* (which mean essentially the same thing), it, too, sounds totally wrong to me. Do you interpret it in the sense I suggested of *Do you have something* ***in mind***? Or do you actually think of it in terms of *Do you have a physical object in your possession that you always forget to do?* If so, do you further parse it as an elliptical version of *Do you have a physical object in your possession that you always forget to do* ***something to***?

Comment: Perhaps an actual example would be better. Does the following make sense to you? *I have a dentist appointment that I always forget to do.* To me, that's mostly nonsense—although I can understand what the sentence is attempting to say. How about *Do you have a burrito that you always forget to do?*

Comment: I interpret it as "is there anything that you always forget to do", but with a greater sense of personal-ness.

I might answer "yes, I always forget to lock the door". Well, I don't but that's an example. And the *always* could be hyperbole rather than literal.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. (We agree on the *is* version!) And I'm guessing the wording sounds *better* to you in a general question than in either a specific question or in any kind of answer.

Comment: I mean, the concrete example of this phrasing that I would point to in a question would be "do you have anything you want to tell me?". It's the same as "is there anything you want to tell me?", but emphasises the personal-ness and the relationship between the speaker and the person they are addressing. I certainly ran into both phrasings a lot as a child... if you don't want that personal-ness, the *is* version is better, but there are reasons for the *have you got* version to be better in some cases. The *is* version is definitely more formal.